# Include Bootstrap in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a Laravel newbie. I have just installed some 3rd party packages and I would like to integrate Twitter bootstrap into my script. Is there any way to do it, short of going into each package and adding the code to the blade templates of each view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the top/header part of my currently running application's master layout:

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/master.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Simple CMS" />
    <meta name="author" content="Sheikh Heera" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href={{ assets("favicon.png") }} />

    <title>LaraPress</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href = {{ asset("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css") }} rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href = {{ asset("bootstrap/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css") }} rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}">
</head>
```

Follow this approach and make your each view to extend the master layout like this:

```
<!-- app/views/user/show.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><label>View User</label>
        <a class ='pull-right' href="{{ Request::header('referer') }}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></i> Go Back
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is a partial of my view (top part) which extends the master layout so it become a part of the master layout. Master layout is stored in `app/views/layouts/` folder and name is `master.blade.php` so, @extends('layouts.master') means to extend `master.blade.php` from `layouts` folder and it (name) could be anything, each view also must contains `.blade` in the file name before the `.php`.

Answer (score 44):

## Update for Laravel 7.*

Within terminal:

```
laravel new project

cd project

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap

npm install && npm run dev
```

Then, in the HTML that you are working on, pull in both the CSS and JavaScript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    ....
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Documentation for [Laravel UI](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend)

@Svyat, hopefully, this answers your question as well.

Happy coding :)

---

I realize that this is old... but it was the top result that come up for me on Google. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

If you are using **Laravel 6.2**,

Within terminal:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Within app.scss:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

In Terminal, run the following to generate /public/css/app.css file:

```
npm run dev
```

Within welcome.blade.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

Happy coding

Comment: After adding `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`, run `npm run dev` to generate /public/css/app.css file.

Comment: And what about the bootstrap.js file? How to import it to your app.js if there's already added "bootstrap.js" (different) from laravel?

Comment: @Syvat, I have updated my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: the Update  method to add bootstrap helped me a lot because i was using now the laravel 8x version so for the next time, i'm gonna use this way to add latest version of bootstrap, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Laravel > 6.x introduced a new approach to deal with frontend scaffolding, [laravel/ui](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend).

You can simply download the composer package:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

And run a artisan command:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Answer (score 3):

The  best way would be to create a master template and have each of your templates extend the master template.

Then in the master template, any time you need to add something like Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery, etc... to your app, you just add to the the master template and then it would be available to each page you have.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a template (you can call it main, if it pleases you). Include the Twitter Bootstrap on it. Extend all of your other blades views from it.

**YES, it's that simple!** =D

Answer (score 0):

Run below command, this will resolve the issue

```
npm i @popperjs/core
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation to your answer, why it should solve the issue?

Comment: I think this is Tooltip & Popover Positioning Engine which bootstrap uses.

Comment: Once this is installed make sure to include <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"> and  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>